# Coveralls in travis-ci

Tags: rspec, travis-ci, coveralls

I have a repository in github using travis-ci

```
  https://github.com/alu0100786330/prct09
```

And I want to integrate coverall with travis, I'm using cloud9 and this is the URL

```
 https://ide.c9.io/alu0100786330/prt9
```

I add to the Gemspec this lines

```
  gem 'coveralls', require: false
```

*To the .coveralls.yml

```
 service_name: travis-ci
 repo_token: kzOty157GlK2mMpKsSAjoeDGJ6bfnfarQ
```

And to the spec_helper in the top

```
 require 'coveralls'
 Coveralls.wear!
```

I execute the `bundle install` and push the changes to the repository and these are the error that appear in my travis

```
    https://travis-ci.org/alu0100786330/prct09
```

[Coverall errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTc9U.png)

How can I fix the mistakes?

Comment: Unsure of the specific answer to your question but you should redact the repo_token value which is private

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must not write your token on a public repository, as someone comentted on your question. Starting by testing it locally.

```
export COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN=my-token
```

Then execute your build commamds on ruby to create the report.
If you already added your github repo at https://coveralls.io/ it should create a report for you. Now you can configure https://travis-ci.com/github/your-repo by going in `more options` -> `settings` -> `Environment Variables` and add `COVERALLS_REPO_TOKEN` and your token.

Now on the `.travis-ci.yml` file you add the same lines that you used to create the coverall report.

```
script:
  - your command to generate the report
after_success:
  - your command to upload the report
```